# Is it possible to change the UI of MSI installer according to the local system language?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, multilingual

Since the default language for the WiX installler UI is english, I'd like to change to another langue like chinese or something. Is there a way can I do?

Comment: See the "Using Localized Versions of WixUI" article in WiX.chm

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a supported way to change the UI of a MSI at install time automatically based on the local system language.

However, if you use WiX v3.6+ with the new bootstrapper/chainer called Burn then it can provide an External UI handler that does automatically detect the local system language.  The "Standard WiX Bootstrapper Application" detects the user's language preference from Windows and will load a .wxl file from the `LCID` folder that matches the user's language.

You can see this all set up in the wix38 branch of the WiX toolset in `src\ext\BalExtension\wixstdba`.